# using slf4j with log4j. log is not created in file when deploy in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat7

I am using slf4j with log4j in my java webapp application. Log file is created when i run this using maven-jetty plugin.  But when i deployed it in tomcat all log appended in catalina.out instead of my log file. Below is my Log4j.xml file

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[test] %p [%t] %c{1}.%M(%L) | %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ROLL" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="/tmp/myApp.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100MB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="50" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss:SSS} - %5p - %C{1}.%M(%L) - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="net.sf.ehcache">
        <level value="ERROR" />
    </logger>

    <!-- Suppress success logging from InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent -->
    <logger name="org.acegisecurity">
        <level value="ERROR" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache">
        <level value="WARN" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.eclipse">
        <level value="ERROR" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="java.sql">
        <level value="ERROR" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="WARN" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.codehaus.mojo">
        <level value="ERROR" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL">
        <level value="ERROR" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="ERROR" />
    </logger>

    <!-- Suppress warnings from Commons Validator -->
    <logger name="org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorResources">
        <level value="ERROR" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.myapp">
        <level value="ERROR" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.myapp">
        <level value="INFO" />
    </logger>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="ROLL" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

---

and maven dependency is as below

---

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

---

Comment: It seems like you're using different loggers for Jetty (log4j) and Tomcat (java.util.logging). Using log4j in both cases should solve the problem. If you're using different loggers intentionaly for some reason, then please post the configuration file for JUL you're using

Comment: do you mean "slf4j" instead "self4j"?

Comment: Have a look in the logfiles/catalina.out whenever the log4j configuration is loaded or not.

Comment: Your maven pom references `slf4j-jdk14` which uses `java.util.logging` instead of log4j. Remove that dependency it conflicts with `slf4j-log4j12`.

Comment: I am using eclipselink in this project and using default logging for this(define the file name in persistence.xml file). I am not using any separate logger for maven-jetty

Comment: @Ralph :sorry you r right. it is slf4j

Comment: thanks all. My problem has resolved. There is issue in dependency. There were cyclic dependency in my project. i was using a plugin com.yammer.dropwizard. It automatically loaded log4j-over-slf4j,ogback-classic,logback-core and jul-to-slf4j and one other spring-data-redis loaded jcl-over-slf4j automatically. after excluding these dependency its resolved

Answer (score 0):

In my case, project had 2 SLF4J implementations, "log4j" and "logback".
On application deployment catalina.out had this message
"SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings....".
Removed logback by dependency exclusion in pom and after that file was created and populated by logs.

See this link
https://www.baeldung.com/slf4j-classpath-multiple-bindings